# How to calculate difference between two cells within the same column in excel?

Tags: excel

As mentioned below, I need to create a separate column for NetCount. The NetCount column should be the difference between the two cells from the count column for each and every hour.

For the 1st hour (Netcount = 60 - 56 = 4)

How can I calculate the netcount column in excel ?

Can anyone please help me out ...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EicXF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your new column write `=$C3-$C4`,

then double click( or drag down) the bottom right corner of the cell.